# What is the relationship between proto package and actual directory structure

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, proto

I have read official docs & tutorial online about protobuf but I still don't quite understand the relationship between the package name & import path in proto definition and actual directory structure.

To make my question clear, let's say this is my project structure:

```
root
├── project
│   └── protos
│       ├── common
│       │   └── common.proto
│       └── custom
│           ├── app.proto
│           └── util
│               └── util.proto
```

common.proto

```proto
syntax = "proto3";

// how should I decide the package for this file based on my project structure?
package project.protos.common;

message Common {
    // ...
}
```

app.proto, which references common.proto (in another separate directory) and util.proto (in subdirectory)

```proto
syntax = "proto3";

package project.protos.custom;

import "project/protos/common/common.proto";
import "project/protos/custom/util/util.proto";
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";

message App {
    project.protos.common.Common common = 3;
    project.protos.custom.util.Util util = 4;
}
```

util.proto

```proto
syntax = "proto3";

package project.protos.custom.util;

option java_multiple_files = true;

message Util {
    // ...
}
```

After doing several trials, it turns out that if I run the protoc command at the **root** directory, using the command:

```sh
protoc -I . --java_out=. project/protos/**/*.proto
```

then imports are working correctly and every proto file is compiled with no error. However, let's say if I run the protoc not at root directory, but at subdirectory project, using similar command:

```sh
protoc -I . --java_out=. protos/**/*.proto
```

Compilation would then fail with following error:

```
project/protos/common/common.proto: File not found.
project/protos/custom/util/util.proto: File not found.
protos/custom/app.proto:6:1: Import "project/protos/common/common.proto" was not found or had errors.
protos/custom/app.proto:8:1: Import "project/protos/custom/util/util.proto" was not found or had errors.
protos/custom/app.proto:19:5: "project.protos.common.Common" seems to be defined in "protos/common/common.proto", which is not imported by "protos/custom/app.proto".  To use it here, please add the necessary import.
protos/custom/app.proto:20:5: "project.protos.custom.util.Util" is not defined.
```

As I'm working with Java for most of times, I'm currently thinking the way that how package & import works in protobuf, with respect to the actual directory structure, is similar to how package & import works in Java, with respect to classpath.

That is, if I want to compile a proto with package specified to be "project.protos.common", then I should run the protoc command on the parent directory of project dir, where project/protos/common is a valid path.

Similarly, if I am importing a proto in another proto file with the import path set to be "project/protos/custom/util/util.proto", then I should also make sure that from the directory when I run protoc command, path project/protos/custom/util/util.proto is present.

I'm currently guessing whatever path we feed into -I option, protoc will treat them in the same way as Java classpath or python search path. Upon importing, protoc will look for the imported file on every specified -I path, following the relative path that is indicated by import statement.

However, after searching online for similar questions and reading some articles, now I have the impression that package and import in protobuf are actually much more flexible than I thought them to be. Is my understanding wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to answer indirectly:

1. Package names correspond to directories
2. One Package may span multiple files in a single directory
3. (But) Individual files must import Protos even if in the same Package
4. It's useful to namespace|scope packages by some org id (e.g. `google` for `timestamp`)
5. A hierarchy (e.g. `google.protobuf` manifest as `google/protobuf/...`) of related Packages is independent of its file system location.
6. Although the Package hierarchy is fixed, there's flexibility in 'placement' when generating language-specific bindings.

I'll try to provide examples of each:

Using `protoc`'s `include` directory as an example, the Package `google.protobuf` clearly identifies this as a `google` originated Package representing `protobuf` "stuff".

The Package must be represented in a directory as `google/protobuf` but it's location in the system is arbitrary and without dependencies (see `--proto_path`).

Files in the package e.g. `api.proto` must import e.g. `type.proto` (using the full namespace path (i.e. `google/protobuf/type.proto`) even though they share a Package.

When running `protoc .... foo.proto`, if `foo.proto` imports `google/protobug/api.proto`, `protoc` needs some means of finding the Package and so `protoc --proto_path=path/to/google` is required (although if `protoc` is in the path, the `include` directory need not be added on Linux). All imports must be similarly `--proto_path`'d.

Where `protoc` outputs files and (more importantly) the namespace used to produce the ouput, has some flexibility thanks to `option [langauge]_package` flags in the proto files.

I'm unfamiliar with Java, but in the case of Golang, I can use `option go_package` to help me specify a Golang Module name (`github.com/[org]/[repo]`) to ensure that the generated files are placed in the repo so that they will be correctly imported by other Golang modules.

Comment: As described in https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial, there is an equivalent `option java_package`.